# How to update value of first entry if it does not exist in any row?

Tags: mysql

I have a weight log table:

```
id     userid   weight   is_start_weight
3      10       100      Y
5      10       98       N
7      11       120      N
9      11       115      N
```

Each user must have start weight flag on first entry to 'Y', but some of them don't and I want to set it.

I can select those users this way:

```
SELECT p.userid
FROM weight_tracker_log p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT s.userid
    FROM weight_tracker_log s
    WHERE p.userid = s.userid AND s.is_start_weight = 'Y'
)
```

Question is how to update `is_start_weight` flag to 'Y'? First user's entry, with lowest `id` has to be updated.

Could be my select is wrong, maybe I should update first entry for each user to 'Y'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the lowest id for each user with a query such as this:

```
update weight_tracker_log wtl join
       (select userid, min(id) as minid
        from weight_tracker_log
        group by userid
       ) u
       on wtl.userid = u.userid and wtl.id = u.minid
    set is_start_weight = 'Y'
    where wtl.is_start_weight <> 'Y';
```

EDIT:

If the existing users could have 'Y' weights on the not-smallest id, then:

```
update weight_tracker_log wtl join
       (select userid, min(id) as minid,
               max(is_start_weight = 'Y') as has_y
        from weight_tracker_log
        group by userid
       ) u
       on wtl.userid = u.userid and wtl.id = u.minid and has_y = 0
    set is_start_weight = 'Y';
```

Comment: How would I do select for this query, in order to check it? What should I order by? I have too many records, just do not want to mess them up.

Comment: My advice:  copy the table before running any code you get on the web.  But, you can replace the `update` with `select * from` and remove the `set` clause to get a similar `select` query.

Comment: I did that and got almost all records (10000), but I know they are only 41. The number 41 is from my query in the question, could be that query is wrong?

Comment: @skobaljic . . . Your query is wrong.  It just checks for the existence of a record with a minimum weight.  It doesn't check that it has the smallest id.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an update join query. Try

```
    update weight_tracker_log 
    inner join (
    SELECT min(p.id) id, p.userid
    FROM weight_tracker_log p
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT s.userid
        FROM weight_tracker_log s
        WHERE p.userid = s.userid AND s.is_start_weight = 'Y'
    )
    group by p.userid
    ) missing
    on weight_tracker_log.id = missing.id
    set weight_tracker_log.is_start_weight = 'Y'
```

See. https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql%20update%20join

Comment: There are some errors in this query. I try convert it to select, but it does not work. `missing.id` is unkown in `on clause`.

Comment: Thank you for your time, anyway. Probably with some small changes it would work correctly.